# C++ isn't changing variable value

Tags: c++

I want the code to get out of the while loop when I input a number other than 66; I made it print the value of 'plz' to see if the value was changing. It is not changing, it stays at 1 even though I typed plz=o;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "welcome to the random number generator, please enter a number\n";
  int plz=1, d;
  d=1;
  while (plz>0)
  {
    d=d+1;
    int g;
    cin >> g;
    g = 666;
    if (g==666)
      int j;
    else
      plz=0;
    cout << plz << "\n";
  }
  srand (d);
  d = rand();
  cout << d << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only change `plz` when `g` is *not* 666; since you just assigned it to be 666, that will never happen.

Comment: thank you, i just noticed that i put cin >> g; before the declaration of g

Comment: If you had, it wouldn't have compiled; but you put `g = 666;` just before the `if`, which results in the behavior I described.

Comment: i mean defining. i put cin >> g; before i defined it.